# Some cell of column is starting from comma so how can i remove it? in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Remove all comma from starting and ending

For Example

```
id name
1  ,,par, ind, gop, abc 
2  ,raj,
3  marl, govin
4  rajjs, sun,,,
```

Ans

```
id name
1  par, ind, gop, abc 
2  raj,
3  marl, govin
4  rajjs, sun
```

Comment: You should do some research before coming here,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python strip function lets you specify a character to strip from the start and end, so this should work:

```
df = df['name'].apply(lambda x: x.strip(','))
```

Or even more simply using the `str` handle to access python string functions:

```
df = df['name'].str.strip(',')
```

And also with a list comprehension (thanks to @Celius Stingher for this suggestion)

```
df['name'] = [x.strip() for x in df['name']]
```

example with data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'name': [',,par, ind, gop, abc', ',raj,', 'marl, govin', 'rajjs', 'sun,,,']
})
df = df['name'].str.strip(',')
print(df)
```

result:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | par, ind, gop, abc |
| 1 | raj |
| 2 | marl, govin |
| 3 | rajjs |
| 4 | sun |

Comment: you can also access string functions without `apply`, using `df['name'].str.strip(',')`

Comment: Can you please help me to solve this questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73393969/dataframe-check-in-each-columns-if-anything-is-repeating-create-new-column-and

Answer (score 1):

You can perform it faster and more efficient way using list comprehensions, avoiding the need for `apply` or lambdas:

```
df['name'] = [x.strip() for x in df['name']]
```